# Map Custom fields of Leads in Salesforce

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, salesforce

I wanted to map custom fields of lead to map with custom field of contact' when converted using `binding.convertLead()`.

It should replicate the behaviour what we are manually doing from UI when custom fields of Lead are mapped with contact (Navigate to *SetUp->Customize->Leads->Fields* then in *Lead Custom Fields & Relationships* section *Map Lead Fields* button.)

I have the C# code to convert a lead into contact.
However I need to map the custom fields of lead to custom fields of contact.

Like for e.g:

1) `Lead.Newsletter__c` (Custom field of check box type in lead)

2) `Contact.Newsletter__c` (Custom field of check box type in contact)

3) Now, if `Lead.Newsletter__c` is checked then when I convert any lead to contact, then `Contact.Newsletter__c` should be checked automatically.

I am able to fetch all the custom fields by using `describeSObjects` of Partener WSDL proxy class, but still unable to located where the changes should be made

Comment: Could you let me know if you are trying to convert a lead through Apex Controller class.?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple design, essentially I would do it in a static mapper class. We definitely need more information to help you, but short of that, here is some ***psuedocode*** (not production code) that should be a sufficient design pattern.

```
public static class CustomMapper
{
    public static void leadToContact(Lead lead, ID contactID)
    {
        var contact = new Contact(contactID);
        ///do mapping here
        ///eg
        ///returnval.Newsletter__c = Lead.Newsletter__c;

        contact.save();
    }
}
```

then for the usage:

```
//convert the lead to a contact prior to usage here, and get the resulting contact id
CustomMapper.leadToContact(myOldLead, myContactID);
```

If you perform the conversion, then immediately after perform the custom mapping with an update, then it will seem instantaneous to the users anyways. Without more information, this is the best, generic design pattern that I could recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided a lot of detail to work with, but can you perhaps use a Linq projection?

eg Leads.Select(x=>new Contact{Newsletter = x.Newsletter});